# Reading in all files with a specific extension

Tags: r

I have several `csv` files which are stored in a folder `"C://Users//Prices//"` I want to read this files in R and store them as a dataframe. I tried a `for loop` however this would take hours to read in all the files(I measured the system.time()).

Can can this be done besides using a for loop?

Comment: It seems your data files are large. Do you really need to load all of them? I don't think there's another solution than a for loop for this, and I don't see how it could make a difference.

Comment: Check `fread` from `data.table` package.  How many files, how large are they?  If you have a large amount of data then `data.table` will be considerably faster to use than `data.frame`.
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/data.table/docs/fread

Comment: @MattWeller I have around 1000 files each 250 KB large. I also saw that `Sys.glob(".csv")` could work. However I only get excetions when I insert my file path

Comment: I'm not sure the number of files or the file size is a major problem.  The loop will be fine, try it for a subset of files with a couple of different approaches.  lukeA's solution will speed things up for a start, see if that makes enough of a difference.   There are various other solutions suggested in the comments under the following blog but I doubt you'll beat `fread`: http://stathack.wordpress.com/2012/12/27/opening-large-csv-files-in-r/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will reiterate that `fread` is significantly quicker as is shown in this post on Stack Overflow: [Quickly reading very large tables as dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r).  In summary, the tests (on a 51 Mb file - 1e6 rows x 6 columns) showed an performance improvement of over 70% against the best alternative methods including `sqldf`, `ff` and `read.table` with and without the optimised setting recommended in the answer by @lukeA.  This was backed up in the comments which report a 4GB file loading in under a minute with `fread`, compared to 15 hours with base functions.

I ran some tests of my own, to compare alternative methods of reading **and combining** CSV files.  The experimental setup is as follows:

1. Generate 4 column CSV file (`character` x 1, `numeric` x 3) for each run.  There are 6 runs, each with a different number of rows, ranging from `10^1`, `10^2`,...,`10^6` records in the data file.
2. Import the CSV file into `R` 10 times, joining with `rbind` or `rbindlist` to create a single table.
3. Test out `read.csv` & `read.table`, with and without optimised arguments such as colClasses, against `fread`.
4. Using `microbenchmark` repeat every test 10 times (probably unnecessarily high!), and collect the timings for each run.

The results show again in favour of `fread` with `rbindlist` over optimised `read.table` with `rbind` functionality.

This table shows the `median` total duration for 10 file reads & combines for each method and number of rows per file. The first 3 columns are in  microseconds, the last 3 in seconds.

```
              expr       10       100     1000     10000    1e+05     1e+06
1:           FREAD  3.93704  5.229699 16.80106 0.1470289 1.324394  12.28122
2:        READ.CSV 12.38413 18.887334 78.68367 0.9609491 8.820387 187.89306
3:   READ.CSV.PLUS 10.24376 14.480308 60.55098 0.6985101 5.728035  51.83903
4:      READ.TABLE 12.82230 21.019998 74.49074 0.8096604 9.420266 123.53155
5: READ.TABLE.PLUS 10.12752 15.622499 57.53279 0.7150357 5.715737  52.91683
```

This plot shows the comparison of timings when run 10 times on the HPC:

[image]

Normalising these values against the `fread` timing shows how much longer these other methods take for all scenarios:

```
                      10      100     1000    10000    1e+05     1e+06
FREAD           1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.000000
READ.CSV        3.145543 3.611553 4.683256 6.535784 6.659941 15.299223
READ.CSV.PLUS   2.601893 2.768861 3.603998 4.750835 4.325023  4.221001
READ.TABLE      3.256838 4.019352 4.433693 5.506811 7.112887 10.058576
READ.TABLE.PLUS 2.572370 2.987266 3.424355 4.863232 4.315737  4.308762
```

*Table of results for 10 `microbenchmark` iterations on the HPC*

Interestingly for 1 million rows per file the optimised version of `read.csv` and `read.table` take 422% and 430% more time than `fread` whilst without optimisation this leaps to around 1500% and 1005% longer.

Note that when I conducted this experiment on my powerful laptop as opposed to the HPC cluster the performance gains were somewhat less (around 81% slower as opposed to 400% slower).  This is interesting in itself, not sure that I can explain it however!

```
                      10      100     1000    10000    1e+05     1e+06
FREAD           1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.000000
READ.CSV        2.595057 2.166448 2.115312 3.042585 3.179500  6.694197
READ.CSV.PLUS   2.238316 1.846175 1.659942 2.361703 2.055851  1.805456
READ.TABLE      2.191753 2.819338 5.116871 7.593756 9.156118 13.550412
READ.TABLE.PLUS 2.275799 1.848747 1.827298 2.313686 1.948887  1.832518

Table of results for only 5 `microbenchmark` iterations on my i7 laptop
```

Given that the data volume is reasonably large I'd suggest the benefits will not only be in the reading of the files with `fread` but in the subsequent manipulation of the data with the `data.table` package as opposed to traditional `data.frame` operations!  I am lucky to have learned this lesson at an early stage and would recommend others to follow suit...

Here is the code used in the tests.

```
rm(list=ls()) ; gc()
library(data.table)  ; library(microbenchmark) 

#=============== FUNCTIONS TO BE TESTED ===============

f_FREAD = function(NUM_READS) {
    for (i in 1:NUM_READS) {
        if (i == 1) x = fread("file.csv") else x = rbindlist(list(x, fread("file.csv"))) 
    } 
}
f_READ.TABLE = function(NUM_READS) {
    for (i in 1:NUM_READS) {
        if (i == 1) x = read.table("file.csv") else x = rbind(x, read.table("file.csv"))
    }
}
f_READ.TABLE.PLUS = function (NUM_READS) {
    for (i in 1:NUM_READS) {
        if (i == 1) {
            x = read.table("file.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE, comment.char="", colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
        } else {
            x = rbind(x, read.table("file.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE, comment.char="", colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric")))
        }
    }       
}
f_READ.CSV = function(NUM_READS) {
    for (i in 1:NUM_READS) {
        if (i == 1) x = read.csv("file.csv") else x = rbind(x, read.csv("file.csv"))
    }
}
f_READ.CSV.PLUS = function (NUM_READS) {
    for (i in 1:NUM_READS) {
        if (i == 1) {
            x = read.csv("file.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
        } else {
            x = rbind(x, read.csv("file.csv", comment.char="", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric")))
        }
    }       
}

#=============== MAIN EXPERIMENTAL LOOP ===============
for (i in 1:6)
{
    NUM_ROWS = (10^i)       # the loop allows us to test the performance over varying numbers of rows
    NUM_READS = 10

    # create a test data.table with the specified number of rows and write it to file
    dt = data.table(
        col1 = sample(letters[],NUM_ROWS,replace=TRUE),
        col2 = rnorm(NUM_ROWS),
        col3 = rnorm(NUM_ROWS),
        col4 = rnorm(NUM_ROWS)
    )
    write.csv(dt, "file.csv", row.names=FALSE)

    # run the imports for each method, recording results with microbenchmark
    results = microbenchmark(
                FREAD = f_FREAD(NUM_READS), 
                READ.TABLE = f_READ.TABLE(NUM_READS),
                READ.TABLE.PLUS = f_READ.TABLE.PLUS(NUM_READS),
                READ.CSV = f_READ.CSV(NUM_READS), 
                READ.CSV.PLUS = f_READ.CSV.PLUS(NUM_READS), 
                times = NUM_ITERATIONS)
    results = data.table(NUM_ROWS = NUM_ROWS, results)
    if (i == 1) results.all = results else results.all = rbindlist(list(results.all, results))      
}

results.all[,time:=time/1000000000]     # convert from nanoseconds
```

Comment: You are growing objects in a loop. Even with data.table, this will create a copy (until adding rows by reference is implemented). Note also that `read.csv` is faster on subsequent reading of the same file. whereas `fread` is fast regardless. Perhaps `rbindlist(lapply(list.files("C://Users//Prices//", pattern = 'csv'), fread)` would be best.

Comment: @mnel Thanks for the update.  I take it `rbindlist` and `lapply` takes no copies at all, just using `fread` to read the csv file straight into the final object.  I agree this would be the best solution for @user2051347

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Good spot by @mnel there, though. In @mnel's suggestion `lapply(<files>,fread)` reads them all separately returning a list of e.g. 10 * 1GB tables. Then the `rbindlist` stacks them into the final single 10GB table. 20GB RAM needed in total, as good as it gets. Whereas the code in this answer as it stands churns through 1GB + 2GB + 3GB + 4GB ... + 10GB = 55GB as it calls rbindlist 9 times rather than once.

Comment: Once this memory churn is removed, `fread` should be even more favourable.

Comment: I will improve my code in a couple of days and set it to run overnight.  Note that the csv files were only 58Mb at their largest (1m recs x 4 cols), else I think my laptop would be in flames by now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Speed up your `read.table` command by

- predefining `colClasses=c("numeric", "factor", ...)`
- setting `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`
- disabling csv comments using `comment.char=""`

Via http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2009/11/loading-big-data-into-r/